# LED Light bulbs always blow prematurely in ceiling fans

Tags: ceiling-fan, led

I've seen related questions to this - where the standard bulbs keep blowing prematurely in a ceiling fan. As a result of the general issues of wobbly fans and possible current instability, I got some LEDs - and for about 2 months the results were astounding.

However, they both just died on me, about a week apart from each other. I'm really left at a loss now as how to proceed. I don't like the wiring in this house - its dodgy at best and down right dangerous otherwise. The previous owners really did not care for taking time etc to be careful. The house has been built and maintained on the cheap.

So - anyone got any ideas what I can do to either fault find or fix this issue?

Comment: As much as I like LED lights, for your application, I'd try rough-service incandescent bulbs, such as http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=100+watt+rough+service+bulbs. These both has extra-strong filaments to resist vibration and also designed for slightly high voltage so that the filament is under less electrical stress.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer... some LED lights are not dimmable. Therefore, if there is a speed switch and/or dimmer switch, make sure that: 1) the LED bulbs are dimmable, 2) the Dimmer/Speed switch is properly rated for fan and LED light use, and 3) the switch is wired properly.

If these are not the case, then the fan could be defective and causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

LED lights are complicated little electronics packages.  they can have voltage controllers, inverters, heat sinks. micorprocessors, etc. on board.  they don't generally like vibration.  however, the oscillatory nature of a ceiling fan is much less prone to damage these devices than impact shocks would.  if your fan is vibrating or oscillating violently, you have to address that first, as no residential luminaire bulb, LED or not is going to last long with constant or intermittent vibration or movement.  they just aren't designed for it.  so assuming that this is not the case, i would suspect you have an intermittent short in the fixture or wiring that is cooking the bulbs.  i would start with checking all connections in the switch, device box and the fan assembly itself.  look for burnt spots, brown spots or melted insulation.  its quite common to see wiring abrasion and arcing at the ball socket that the fan is suspended from.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but may help still help someone. I think this issue is more likely that the led bulb is on the same switch circuit as the fan. As the fan motor is inductive, it can create a surge on start up which can blow the electonics in a led bulb after a short time. There are suppressors available that can be wired across the mains to absorb this inrush of current